# "Converting circular structure to JSON" error in fully mocked Jest test

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

I have a function that returns a Promise:

```
  isKontoValid(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(
          !this.kontoComponent.form.invalid &&
            this.dataService.data.checkout.konto.hasSepaEinwilligung,
        );
      });
    });
  }
```

And this test for it:

```
it('should return true if kontoComponent form is valid and hasSepaEinwilligung is true', async () => {
  component['dataService'].data.checkout.konto.hasSepaEinwilligung = false;
  const result = await component.isKontoValid().then();
  expect(result).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Despite everything the function uses I get this error:

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>     --> starting at object with constructor 'Zone'
>     |     property '_zoneDelegate' -> object with constructor '_ZoneDelegate'
>     --- property 'zone' closes the circle
>     at stringify (<anonymous>)
> ```

I don't really understand it, because, as I said, both `this.kontoComponent.form.invalid` and `this.dataService.data.checkout.konto.hasSepaEinwilligung` is mocked in the test. And there is also no conversion to JSON happening in the test nor the function.

I suppose I somehow handle the asynchrony wrong somehow!?

Answer (score 0):

You can't not use like this

```js
it('should return true if kontoComponent form is valid and hasSepaEinwilligung is true', async () => {
  component.kontoComponent.form = { invalid: false } as any;
  component['dataService'].data.checkout.konto.hasSepaEinwilligung = true;
  expect(await component.isKontoValid()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

You can do like this and this works!

```js
it('should return true if kontoComponent form is valid and hasSepaEinwilligung is true', async () => {
  component.kontoComponent.form = new FormGroup({
    yourFormName: new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
  });
  component['dataService'].data.checkout.konto.hasSepaEinwilligung = true;
  expect(await component.isKontoValid()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the problem here. I use `component.kontoComponent.form = { invalid: false } as any;` in other tests and it works perfectly fine.
My problem here has something to do with the result of this: `await component.isKontoValid().then()`